# Proving a property of a certain function $f:[0,1] \to R$

Tags: inequality

Consider a function $f:[0,1 ]\to R $ defined by $$ f(x)=\frac{1-x}{1+x}.$$ How can we show that for $x,y \in [0,1]$:
$$ f(x)+f(y) \geq f(xy).$$ I tried but get stuck in the end.We have the inequality holds iff
$$\frac{1-x}{1+x}+\frac{1-y}{1+y} \geq \frac{1-xy}{1+xy} \geq \frac{1-xy}{(1+x)(1+y)}.$$ That will be true if $$ (1-x)(1+y)+(1-y)(1+x) \geq 1-xy.$$

Comment: Did you try multiplying out the products on LHS of your last inequality? The proof is quite trivial.

Comment: yes ,i tried. it gives $2-2(x+y)-2xy \geq 1-xy.$Tha means $1-2(x+y)-xy \geq 0.$ Now this one is not obvious to me

Comment: You are making some msitake. It should reduce to $xy \leq 1$ which is certainly true.

Comment: yes i think so.could you kindly point it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identically we have
$$
\frac{1-x}{1+x}
+
\frac{1-y}{1+y}
-
\frac{1-xy}{1+xy}
=
\frac
{(1-x)(1-y)(1-xy)}
{(1+x)(1+y)(1+xy)}
\ge
0
$$
Alternatively, continuing from where you left off
\begin{align*}
&
(1-x)(1+y)+(1-y)(1+x) \ge 1-xy
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
2-2xy\ge 1-xy
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
1\ge xy
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which is true.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun: With the substitution $x=e^{-u}$ your inequality is equivalent to showing that
$$
 g(u) = f(e^{-u}) = \tanh(u/2)
$$
satisfies
$$g(u+v) \le g(u) + g(v)
$$
for $u \ge 0$, and that is true because a concave function $g:[0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ with $g(0) \ge 0$ is [subadditive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity#Functions).